# The glyph is rendered as an empty box using pillow

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to render every character in different fonts, and some fonts give me empty boxes instead of characters, and I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong, I tried to change the layout engine, I was playing with encoding, but still I sometimes get empty boxes, and I really don't want to go through 250 thousand images to remove these empty boxes

My code is presented below:

```
def draw_glyph(font_file, unicode_char, glyph_size=128):

try:
    font = ImageFont.truetype(
        font=f"{font_file}",
        encoding="",
        size=glyph_size,
        layout_engine=ImageFont.LAYOUT_RAQM,
    )
except Exception:
    font = None

if font is not None:
    img = Image.new('L', (glyph_size, glyph_size), 'white')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.text(
        xy=(64, 64),
        text=unicode_char,
        font=font,
        anchor='mm',
    )
    return img
return None
```

Comment: Please show some representative code that actually causes a problem - presumably there is some readily identifiable character that you can try to render in some readily available font to get some demonstrable empty box and some readable error message? Thank you.

Comment: There are no errors in the console, it renders the character in png format without any problems.
Just instead of a symbol there is an empty box.
To clarify, the case is as I understood it specifically in the font, but I just physically can't remove every problematic font because their number is more than 3900.
Also an interesting detail is that if you just open this font, it outputs all the letters without any problems.

Comment: Also, to understand what this code does, I'll say that I just run each letter from A to Z in uppercase and lowercase through this function, passing the font name as well as the parameter (I can't upload a picture, so I can only describe it this way).

Comment: StackOverflow guidelines call for a *"Minimal, complete, runnable example"* - which your code cannot be as it only defines some functions without ever calling them and doesn't specify a font, nor which characters don't work.

Comment: An empty box glyph most likely means you're trying to display a character that's not supported by the selected font. Provide more details about what font(s) you're using and what characters you're drawing.

Comment: @PeterConstable, you're right, it is.
Why didn't I understand it right away, thank you very much! The question can be considered closed

Comment: @PeterConstable, you're right, it is.
Why didn't I understand it right away, thank you very much! The question can be considered closed